# Make URLs pretty with one line of htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I've had this issue for some time and originally I just dealt with it the long way around but that didn't work so I was hoping for a more solid solution.

My problem currently is that using the following code:

`RewriteRule ^error/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ error.php?id=$1`

error.php?id=404 becomes this:

`/error/404/`

Which is perfect. However if I add a new page which uses an id at the end, I have to add it in to my htaccess which is extra work and doesn't seem very good in terms of best practice.

I was hoping with one line I could have all sorts of combinations but it doesn't work.

I tried the following which resulted in a default 300 multiple request error.

`RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ $1.php?id=$2`

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Example: `/error/404/` will be rewritten to `/error.php?id=404` if `error.php` exists

Note: maybe you'll have to disable `MultiViews` option (apache content negociation)

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this worked perfectly. Also the MultiViews option wasn't an issue for me. Thanks! :)